# Listing Combinations

Tags: combinatorics

Given $n$ distinct objects, we know that there is an easy way to determine the number of combinations we can obtain of $k$ objects - $\binom{n}{k}$. However, is there a way to *generate* these combinations with a function? For example, if I give it a seed $ 1 \leq j \leq \binom{n}{k}$, the function $f(j)$ returns a particular combination.

Comment: The easy way for small values of $k$ is  some nested loops, with $0 < i_1 < n$, $i_1 < i_2 < n$, $i_2 < i_3 < n$, etc. For efficient and general methods see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/127704/7231208).

Comment: I think what you want is the [Combinatorial Number System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system).